# Using GCM on both Android and iOS without a notification payload

Tags: android, ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement push notifications on both Android and iOS with Google Cloud Messaging.

I don't want to use the `notification` key in my payload because the Android behavior is not ideal. On Android, I would prefer my receiver to always get triggered with the `data` payload, and I can construct the `Notification` myself using `NotificationCompat`. If you use the `notification` payload on Android, you have no control over the notification style, for example.

However, if I only send a `data` payload, I think my iOS app will not receive the push if it is backgrounded - killed, never launched since device restart, etc. I think there's that `content_available` flag for GCM which may trigger the push anyway?

Am I, on iOS, able to duplicate the Android behavior of always having my in-app code execute upon notification? I'd be fine constructing my own iOS notification based on the GCM `data` payload, and perhaps using something like a `UILocalNotification`, but from what I'm reading, iOS is requiring the `notification` payload to exist to make sure the push is always received by the user.

Can I get this kind of control on iOS?

Comment: How to avoid notification to be displayed in notification center in android. Even if I don't include notification payload inside gcm message the notification is getting displayed with blank text and app name as title.

Comment: Got it working. content_available set to false won't show any notification regardless of app in background or foreground. I can handle the notification inside onMessageReceived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research, it seems that you can't avoid using the `notification` payload. However, you can get rid of the default Android behavior of auto-creating a notification, if, instead of creating a `MyGcmListenerService` that extends `GcmListenerService`, you create your own `GcmListenerService` and extend plain old `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the `content_available` flag to `false`, so that it works on Ios as expected and provide full control on android,

Source:- I have worked on Push Notification on both android and IOS recently

Comment: OK, but then should I construct a UILocalNotification myself?