# Not receiving push notifications if sending "data" (but "notification" works) payloads to GCM/FCM in iOS didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get "data" payload notifications to be received for our iOS app.

Today we can send GCM `notification` push notifications as according to:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

(FCM has the same text)

An easy test is using CURL:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
  -H 'authorization: key=##_GCM_SERVER_ID_##' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: ##_POSTMAN_TOKEN_##' \
  -d '{
    "notification": {
        "body": "Test body"
    },
    "to" : "##_DEVICE_TOKEN_##"
}
'
```

This will successfully trigger iOS `AppDelegate.didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` function.

However, if change it to a `data` notification:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
  -H 'authorization: key=##_GCM_SERVER_ID_##' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: ##_POSTMAN_TOKEN_##' \
  -d '{
    "data": {
        "body": "Test body"
    },
    "to" : "##_DEVICE_TOKEN_##"
}
'
```

I can't see anything is being sent to the app from GCM (in either `didReceiveRemoteNotification` functions), even if the app is in background/foreground.

Even though it says in the documentation it should:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

> Note these further platform-specific details:
>
> - On Android, data payload can be retrieved in the Intent used to launch your activity.
> - On iOS, data payload will be found in didReceiveRemoteNotification:.

GCM can handle pure `data` push notifications to the APN network right?

Do I need to do anything special to receive `data`, compared to `notification`, Push Notifications in iOS?

Comment: Maybe due to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019064/80389

Comment: yes i experience the same issue. Found any work around?

Answer (score 4):

When sending the Data type message with FCM to iOS devices, they will only be received if `content_available` is set to `true` in your FCM request body, eg:

```
{
    "to": "--fcm-token--",
    "content_available": true,
    "data": {
        "priority": "high",
        "hello": "world"
    }
}
```

Comment: "content_available" is the key here!

Comment: this is the right answer, this is ther rightttttttt answer.....

Comment: Yesterday, this works very well, Now its no longer working, please what might be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the notes that you've shared, please don't miss out that,

> On iOS, GCM stores the message and delivers it only when the app is in the foreground and has established a GCM connection.

With this, you may want to check [Establishing a Connection](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#connecting). Then, when your XMPP connection is established, CCS and your server use normal XMPP `<message>` stanzas to send JSON-encoded messages back and forth. The body of the `<message>` must be:

```
<gcm xmlns:google:mobile:data>
    JSON payload
</gcm>
```

Also, note that `message_id` is a required field for data message. Check this sample request format for message with payload - data message shown in [Downstream Messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#format). You just have to convert it using CURL.

```
<message id="">
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
  {
      "to":"REGISTRATION_ID",  // "to" replaces "registration_ids"
      "message_id":"m-1366082849205" // new required field
      "data":
      {
          "hello":"world",
      }
      "time_to_live":"600",
      "delay_while_idle": true/false,
      "delivery_receipt_requested": true/false
  }
  </gcm>
</message>
```

For more information, see [XMPP Connection Server Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref).